# WinRT Smooth Grid.Column change Animation

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm using the following code to change a ListView location from one column to another:

```
<Grid.Resources>
  <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
    <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="detailItems" />
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="detailItems2"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)">
      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                              Value="1" />
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
  </Storyboard>
</Grid.Resources>
```

This works, but, there's no animation, it just changes column. I want it to have a sort of translation animation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be done by just changing the (Grid.Column)

What you can do is animate the RenderTransform Property (use a TranslateTransform as its instance).

Animate the TranslateTransform using various keyframes, once this animation is done, reset the TranslateTransform to 0 and change the Grid.Column.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. 
By doing that, I have to exactly know by pixel size where the element will end up when the Grid.Column changes, right?
I might use a stackPanel instead. It might do what I intend.